# Running Windows 10 Pro, Updated Assistant states that "Windows 10 will work on this PC"

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update

My PC Is already running Windows 10, yet the Update Assistant is popping up saying that "Windows 10 will work on this PC".

Does it not realise I am already running Windows 10?

Comment: which windows 10 build do you run? 1511?

Comment: It's listed as 10240

Comment: ok, I explained it in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Build 10240 is the original Windows 10 from July 2015. There are already 2 new Feature Updates out, that replace this version for Home users (November 2015 Update 1511 - Build 10586 and the Windows 10 Anniversary update 1607 - Build 14393).

With the newer updates, the Hardware requirements sometimes change, so the Update Assistant tool tries it you can run the latest version or not.